# Padding a fixed number with leading zeros up to a fixed length

Tags: crystal-reports, report, padding, formula, zero

In Crystal Report using Visual Studio 2010, I am trying a to create a formula for the following scenario:

x = any number (Fixed number of 8 digits, cant be less or greater)

If Length of X is less than 8, pad the required amount of 0's in the front to make its length 8.

Eg:

```
X = 123
Result of Formula should be 00000123

X = 9
Result of Formula should be 00000009
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note - you can't have a number with leading zeroes, as zeroes on the left have no mathematical purpose. You will have to convert your number to a string before it can be rendered.

Comment: Hmm.. yes makes sense in what you say. Might as well use a string then.

Comment: I got it
 
Right("0000"&{MyFieldToPad},8)
 
Works perfectly as I want it to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it

```
Right("0000"&{MyFieldToPad},8)
```

Works perfectly as I want it to.

Answer (score 30):

`ToText({table.field},"00000000")` is more succinct.

Comment: I dont understand what was so  ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad in the question that it is marked as ClOSED. Seriously, guys who understood the point of the question already answered it and now what sense does it make to CLOSE it.

Comment: This formula does not work for me. Isn't the format mask for date fields only?

Comment: ToText     ->   =Text