# How can I set a mask to field of database on crystal report (visual studio 2008)

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports-2008

I try to set a mask if the string have less characters. 
Like this: 
expected = 00000001
real= 001

Comment: possible duplicate of [Padding a fixed number with leading zeros up to a fixed length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989266/padding-a-fixed-number-with-leading-zeros-up-to-a-fixed-length)

Answer (score 0):

Really I used this code and worked it!

```
ReplicateString ("0",8-Length(cstr(ToNumber({SAGFacturaSOP.NumFactura}),0))) + cstr(ToNumber({SAGFacturaSOP.NumFactura}),0)
```