# Crystal reports Concatenate String without commas?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to concatenate two strings in Crystal Reports 2013SP5, but it looks like it is inserting commas even though I did not ask for it.

```
ToText(CurrentDateTime, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ToText(PageNumber)
```

Or

```
ToText(CurrentDateTime, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & ToText(PageNumber)
```

Both prints:

```
201710240756231,00
```

If I use only `ToText(CurrentDateTime, "yyyyMMddhhmmss")` I get `20171024080121`, so the `&` and `+` operators append the `,` between.

I would like the result without commas. (Reason is, I am trying to create a BarCode from these in the format of `yyyyMMddhhmmss XXX`, where the `XXX` is the pagenumber like 001, 002.. 999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two decimals are shown by default if you convert a number to text.

You can set the number of decimals with the second argument of the `ToText`-function:

```
ToText(CurrentDateTime, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & ToText(PageNumber, 0)
```

If you also want to remove the thousands-separator the you can set the third argument to `""`:

```
ToText(CurrentDateTime, "yyyyMMddhhmmss") & ToText(PageNumber, 0, "")
```

Comment: Is there any way to print the PageNumber as fixed length? I am trying to create a BarCode from these two.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989266/padding-a-fixed-number-with-leading-zeros-up-to-a-fixed-length