# Adding leading zeros to Record Number field in Crystal Reports 13

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to add leading zeros to 'Record Number' special field provided by Crystal Reports 13.

Eg:

- Record Number 1 should be '001'
- Record Number 20 should be '020'

I have noticed that there's a related post about customizing table fields by using `ToText({table.field},"000")`. But this approach doesn't work when I use `{recordnumber}` instead of `{table.field}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding a fixed number with leading zeros up to a fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989266/padding-a-fixed-number-with-leading-zeros-up-to-a-fixed-length)

Comment: @MatSnow edited the main question according to my problam.

Comment: @PraveenaGoonasekera you are not going to use `{recordnumber}` just use `recordnumber`. { } are just for fields, see my answer. Just tested here and it's working pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new formula to your desired field, then add this:

```
Right(("000" + ToText(({Comand.YourField}), 0, "")), 3)
```

That's it (note that if you need more zeros you can edit the formula. For 10 digits it will be `Right(("0000000000" + ToText(({Comand.YourField}), 0, "")), 10)` and so on.

As you completed your question, if you want RecordNumber use this way:

```
Right(("000" + ToText((RecordNumber), 0, "")), 3)
```

Comment: Hi @jhenrique, '{Comand.YourField}' only gives access to fields in my data source. How to use the Special Field 'Record Number' provided by CR to be used in that instance?

Comment: You can use the RecordNumber, it's a variable just like other normal data source field. Create a new formula, but using like this: `Right(("000" + ToText((RecordNumber), 0, "")), 3)`